# What traits are implemented by unit type?

Tags: rust

http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ gives no explicit answer and has no separate page for () unlike for the other primitive types.

It looks like unit implements the same traits as tuples in general:
*Clone

PartialEq

Eq

PartialOrd

Ord

Default*,
but at the same time unit is treated separately from tuples everywhere in the documentation.

Comment: There's a page now: [`std::unit::unit`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/unit/primitive.unit.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just writing a page for `()` now: PR [#15321](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/15321)... and now visible as [`std::unit::unit`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/unit/primitive.unit.html).

In the interim, Rust is quite greppable, and grepping for `impl.*for *()` turns up a pile of `impl`s (however, it's not all of them, since some are generated by macros):

```
src/libcollections/hash/mod.rs:150:        impl<S: Writer> Hash<S> for () {
src/libcore/cmp.rs:211:    impl PartialEq for () {
src/libcore/cmp.rs:243:    impl PartialOrd for () {
src/libcore/cmp.rs:270:    impl Ord for () {
src/libcore/fmt/mod.rs:740:impl Show for () {
src/libdebug/repr.rs:39:impl Repr for () {
src/librand/rand_impls.rs:192:impl Rand for () {
src/librustc/util/ppaux.rs:509:impl Repr for () {
src/libserialize/json.rs:2209:impl ToJson for () {
src/libserialize/serialize.rs:361:impl<E, S:Encoder<E>> Encodable<S, E> for () {
src/libserialize/serialize.rs:367:impl<E, D:Decoder<E>> Decodable<D, E> for () {
src/libsyntax/ext/quote.rs:150:    impl ToSource for () {
```

(as well as a pile in tests.)

In summary, the traits of interest there are: `Hash`, `PartialEq`, `PartialOrd`, `Ord`, `Show`, `Rand`, `ToJson`, `Encodable`, `Decodable`. There's also at least `Default`, `TotalEq`, `Clone` via macros.

Comment: Of course there can also be some `impl<T: U> V for T` where  `()`’s implementing `U` implies a `V` implementation.